# Create button in php and call function onclick

Tags: php

I am using a php file ( not HTML ). I want to create a button and call a function when I click it. I try it but `onclick` is not working.

My code:

```
echo "<input type= 'button' value='save' onclick='save()'>";
echo " <script>
    function save(){ alert('save func');}
</script>";
```

**edit 1:**
in the web console: save is not defined. The error occures from:

```
onclick='save()';
```

i try:

```
onclick='javascript:save()';
```

but, the same error.

Comment: To be noted that the OP edited the question after two answers came up fixing the code and making it WORK. There should be more attention when asking. If it's just a minimal example, at least make sure it does not diverge from important parts of the original one.

Comment: Sorry but, I were hurry.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple things wrong in your code. Change it to:

```
echo "<input type='button' value='save'
    onclick='save()'>";

echo "<script>
    function save(){ alert('save func');}
 </script>";
```

---

Here is what I changed:

- removed white space () between `<` and `input`;
- replaced uppercase letters with lowercase;
- changed from `\` to `/` in the `</script>`.

---

Since you said that it wasn't working, I assume that the missing space was a typo in the question only, so *the main problems* in your code were: the uppercase `F` in `function` and using `\` where it should be `/`.

---

---

**References:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types

> JavaScript is case-sensitive [...]

---

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction

> Tags are enclosed by angle brackets, and the closing tag begins with a
>   forward slash.

Comment: Sorry for that but, i type the code not copy and paste it. I am sure that my syntax is correct. But, onclick not working!

Comment: @Alaa You could check the console and inspect the page's code to see if everything is OK too...

Comment: i edit my post. there is no syntax error. i open the console and see that save is not defined!

Comment: the error occures here: onclick='save()'. i try: onclick='javascript:save()' but, the same error!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: you're using HTML

- the `<\script>` tag is not correct, use `</script>` instead
- remove the space before `< input`
- JavaScript function must be lowercase `function`

Your code should be something like that

```
echo "<input type='button' value='save' onclick='save()'>";

echo "<script>
        function save(){ alert('save func');}
    </script>";
```

**EDIT** I copied the code on jsbin, and it works fine! https://output.jsbin.com/ratewijaro

Comment: Sorry for that but, i type the code not copy and paste it. I am sure that my syntax is correct. But, onclick not working!

Comment: i open the web console and it say: save is not defined.

Comment: the error occures here: onclick='save()'. i try: onclick='javascript:save()' but, the same error!

Comment: the only thing that I can say to you is to inspect your page and post your html code into jsbin and see what's happen

Comment: @DiegoMariani isn't it hard when the op seems to hold information or doesn't show the original code? First they clearly lack attention when posting the question. Then we are stuck with a code that seems to work for everyone else but the OP. I'm about to flag the question as off-topic cause the problem can't be reproduced...

Comment: @Diego Mariani The onclick is working in .html file but iam using .php file this is the only difference. I try to write save function at global but the same error. Save() is not defined!